# In mysql how to select columns in a union join

Tags: mysql, join, union

How to select join table's columns when I'm using union. Specifically how to select b.id(booking id) in the following query? Also is it the right way to do it? Can you please tell me any other way to do it? I also want to select available time for a selected date if any available. I have three categories of timing.

> cat1(category 1): availability on particular days of week(Example:Mon, Tue, Wed, etc of any month)
>
> cat2(category 2): availability on First monday, second saturday, etc    of any months.
>
> cat3(category 3): availability on last saturday, last friday, etc of
>      any month.
>
> I'm using day_offset, and cat columns in my doctor_schedule table to calculate date and checking it to @selected_date. I am also filtering off days with the help of my off_day table (off_days table stores information for any holidays, or if doctor taking leave for any personal reasons).

```
mysql> select * from doctor;
    +----+-------------+
    | id | name        |
    +----+-------------+
    |  1 | John Doe    |
    |  2 | Larry Jones |
    +----+-------------+

mysql> select * from doctor_schedule;
+----+-----------+-----+------------+----------+---------------+--------+------------+-----+
| id | doctor_id | day | start_time | end_time | booking_limit | active | day_offset | cat |
+----+-----------+-----+------------+----------+---------------+--------+------------+-----+
|  1 |         2 |   5 | 10:00:00   | 12:00:00 |             1 |      1 |          3 |   2 |
|  2 |         2 |   5 | 19:00:00   | 22:00:00 |             1 |      1 |          3 |   2 |
|  3 |         2 |   6 | 19:00:00   | 22:00:00 |             1 |      1 |          0 |   3 |
+----+-----------+-----+------------+----------+---------------+--------+------------+-----+

mysql> select * from booking;
+----+---------+-------------+--------------+------+
| id | user_id | schedule_id | booking_date | paid |
+----+---------+-------------+--------------+------+
|  1 |       1 |           3 | 2017-06-26   |    1 |
+----+---------+-------------+--------------+------+

mysql> select * from off_day;
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+
| id | doctor_id | schedule_id | date       |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+
|  2 |         1 |           3 | 2017-06-26 |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+

set @selected_date := "2017-06-26";
set @doctor_id := 2;
SET @first_day = DATE_SUB(@selected_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(@selected_date) - 1 DAY);

select s.*
 from
(select
    s1.id
from doctor_schedule s1
where
    s1.cat = 1
and
    s1.day = weekday(@selected_date)
UNION
select
    s2.id
from doctor_schedule s2
where
    s2.cat = 2
and
     DATE_ADD(@first_day, INTERVAL (s2.day - WEEKDAY(@first_day)) + (s2.other*7) DAY) = @selected_date
UNION
select
    s3.id
from doctor_schedule s3
where
    s3.cat = 3
and
    date_sub(LAST_DAY(@selected_date), INTERVAL ((7 + WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(@selected_date)) - s3.other) % 7) DAY) = @selected_date
) as s
right join
    booking b
on
    s.id = b.schedule_id
and 
    b.booking_date >= @selected_date
and
    b.paid = 1
left join
    off_day o
on
    s.id = o.schedule_id
and
    o.date = @selected_date
and
    o.doctor_id = @doctor_id
where
    o.schedule_id is null

group by
    s.id
```

Comment: `booking_id` doesn't appear anywhere in your query.  In this case, you should at least show us your table definitions.

Comment: I have posted my tables.

Comment: Mr. Tim Biegeleisen pointed that there is no booking_id in my query. Thanks to him that I found the solution.

Comment: To give you some general advice: Next time you ask a SQL question here, show us sample input and the output you expect.  Oftentimes, this is more helpful than showing us your current query (which may be far off from what you actually need).

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Tim Biegeleisen pointed that there is no booking_id in my query. Thanks to him that I found the solution. It should be **b.id**.

```
set @selected_date := "2017-06-26";
    set @doctor_id := 2;
    SET @first_day = DATE_SUB(@selected_date, INTERVAL 

DAYOFMONTH(@selected_date) - 1 DAY);

select s.*, b.id
 from
(select
    s1.id
from doctor_schedule s1
where
    s1.cat = 1
and
    s1.day = weekday(@selected_date)
UNION
select
    s2.id
from doctor_schedule s2
where
    s2.cat = 2
and
     DATE_ADD(@first_day, INTERVAL (s2.day - WEEKDAY(@first_day)) + (s2.other*7) DAY) = @selected_date
UNION
select
    s3.id
from doctor_schedule s3
where
    s3.cat = 3
and
    date_sub(LAST_DAY(@selected_date), INTERVAL ((7 + WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(@selected_date)) - s3.other) % 7) DAY) = @selected_date
) as s
right join
    booking b
on
    s.id = b.schedule_id
and 
    b.booking_date >= @selected_date
and
    b.paid = 1
left join
    off_day o
on
    s.id = o.schedule_id
and
    o.date = @selected_date
and
    o.doctor_id = @doctor_id
where
    o.schedule_id is null

group by
    s.id
```

Comment: This may appear to fix your problem, but your query has a problem because you are grouping by the `s.id` column, but selecting `b.id` which does not appear in aggregate.

Comment: Is there any other solution to this query?

Comment: Update your question with a problem description and show us clear expected output.  Someone can probably give you a cleaner query than what you have right now.